# Why is my confidence interval wrong?

Tags: confidence-interval

I'm working through the questions in [this book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/McGraw-Hills-500-Statistics-Questions/dp/0071798722/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1410933282&sr=8-1&keywords=500+statistics+questions). One question asks to construct a 90% confidence interval when the variable has a mean of 11 and a standard deviation of 1.8, and n = 4.

Here's my workings out:

sd/sqrt(n) = 1.8/sqrt(4) = 1.8/2 = 0.9

Upper = 11 + 1.645 x 0.9 = 12.48

Lower = 11 + 1.645 x 0.9 = 9.52

So my 90% confidence interval is 9.5-12.5.

But the book says the 90% confidence interval is 8.9-13.1.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: A confidence interval for what quantity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the sample size is small, the confidence interval determination should be based on a t-distribution. That way you can get the answer given in the book.